# PhatntomJs with Selenium is not able to start session

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, headless-browser

I am using PhantomJs with Selenium for headless automation. It worked well for me until today. Now, I am getting the below exception when I am initializing the PhantomJs driver.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
((DesiredCapabilities)caps).setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\src\\main\\resources\\phantomjs.exe");

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

ERROR:

> ```
>  Jul 27, 2016 9:20:01 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService  INFO:
> executable: C:\Users\Ajatshatru
> Singh\workspace\Assignment\src\main\resources\phantomjs.exe Jul 27,
> 2016 9:20:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService
>  INFO: port: 48904 Jul 27, 2016 9:20:01 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService  INFO:
> arguments: [--webdriver=48904, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Users\Ajatshatru
> Singh\workspace\Assignment\phantomjsdriver.log] Jul 27, 2016 9:20:01
> PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService  INFO:
> environment: {} Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
> start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
> server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.39.0',
> revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time:
> '2013-12-16 13:18:38' System info: host: 'Ajatshatru', ip:
> '10.31.32.236', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51' Driver info: driver.version:
> PhantomJSDriver   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:110)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
>   at Partik.Assignment.WebDriverQueue.main(WebDriverQueue.java:37)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting
> for driver server to start. Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision:
> '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16
> 13:18:38' System info: host: 'Ajatshatru', ip: '10.31.32.236',
> os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2',
> java.version: '1.7.0_51' Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
>   ... 6 more Caused by:
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
> for [http://localhost:48904/status] to be available after 20004 ms    at
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
>   ... 8 more Caused by:
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
>   ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
>   ... 10 more
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple restart did it for me. :|